# Show notifications in lock screen by flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

How can I show an notification in lock screen by using flutter ?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Flutter Local Notification if you want local notifications, otherwise use FCM,

Flutter Local Notification - https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications